# Algorithm for generating lists of shuffled Integers from one original list of Integers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, statistics

Having an ArrayList of `x` unique `Integers`, I need to distribute them shuffled between `y` ArrayLists of `z` size. Take in mind that:

- `x y z` are variable values.
- Numbers can't be repeated on the resulting arrays.
- The resulting lists must not contain the same numbers! (ordering them they must be different)
- Each number of the original array must be used as far as possible the same number of times than the others if you count the occurrences in the resulting arrays.
- All the numbers of the original array must be used, none of
  them can't be non used.
- Must work in Java 7 if it's possible. Not 100% mandatory but...
- The resulting combinations will be used for something similar to a Lottery, so they must not be too much consecutive and must be very randomized. Also they will be presented sorted, from min to max.
- Originally I tried generating all the possible combinations with the objective of getting just the required quantity but it's not viable because if you select high values like 40 numbers in combinations of 11, there are millions and the CPU gets stuck calculating for a lot of time, so I tried to develop a simpler algorithm without calculating all the combinations (I'm posting the code below).

One sample would be this, when you have an origin of an array of 8 elements and you want a output of 3 arrays of 6 size:

> original arraylist: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

> resulting output: [7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 8], [7, 5, 1, 8, 2, 3], [8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

I developed an algorithm which is explained on the comments. First I created an array with the total places and calculate how many times must be repeated each number to fill the output arrays. Then I fill the array with each number repeated the necessary times, and if the array is not full (because when I divide to get the `placesByNumber` I'm rounding to integer) I'm filling it with random numbers from the original set of numbers. After that I shuffle the numbers, and finally after that I fill the resulting arrays taking in mind that I can't repeat numbers in each resulting array.

The problem comes here, sometimes, I'm getting the case that the last array is not completely filled because the last numbers of the shuffled `numbersGroup` variable are contained in that last array.

This is a sample of a failure:

> original arraylist: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>
> shuffled group of numbers for fill the resulting arrays:
>
> [8, 2, 4, 4, 5, 7, 2, 3, 8, 2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 6, 1]

> resulting arrays: (the third doesn't have 6 elements because 6 and 1 are
> contained on it)
>
> [[8, 2, 4, 5, 7, 3], [4, 2, 8, 1, 5, 7], [2, 1, 6, 3]]

I found some very ugly ways to solve it but are very inefficient ways and I'm trying to find a better and efficient algorithm for achieving this.

This is my source code:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> getOptimizedCombinations(List<Integer> numbers, int numbersPerCombination, int desiredCombinations){
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //calculate total places and how many places correspond to each number.
    int totalPlaces = numbersPerCombination * desiredCombinations;
    int placesByNumber = totalPlaces / numbers.size();
    
    //instantiating array with the total number of places
    Integer[] numbersGroup = new Integer[totalPlaces];
    
    //filling the array with the numbers, now we know how many times a number must be inside the array, 
    //so we put the numbers. First we do it in order, later we will shuffle the array.
    int pos = 0;
    for (int n : numbers) {
        for (int i=0; i<placesByNumber; i++) {
            numbersGroup[pos] = n;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    
    //if there are places for fill, we fill it with random numbers. This can be possible because when we divide the total places between the 
    //numbers size, it can give a decimal as a result, and we round it to lower binary number without decimals, so it is possible to
    //have non filled places.       
    if (pos<totalPlaces) {
        while(pos<totalPlaces) {                
            numbersGroup[pos] = numbers.get(getRandom(0, numbers.size()));
            pos++;              
        }
    }       
    
    shuffleArray(numbersGroup);
    
    //we instantiate the arraylists
    for (int i=0; i<desiredCombinations; i++) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
                    
    //filling the arraylists with the suffled numbers
    for (int i=0; i<numbersGroup.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<result.size(); j++) {
            //if the combination doesn't have the number and the combination is not full, we add the number
            if (!result.get(j).contains(numbersGroup[i]) && result.get(j).size()<numbersPerCombination) {
                result.get(j).add(numbersGroup[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

static void shuffleArray(Integer[] ar){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}

public static int getRandom(int min, int max) {
    return (int)(Math.random() * max + min);
}
```

which is called this way:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ 
        add(1); 
        add(2);
        add(3); 
        add(4); 
        add(5); 
        add(6); 
        add(7);
        add(8);
    }};
    getOptimizedCombinations(numbers, 6, 3);
```

Comment: Why not just shuffle the original array, truncate it at the desired size then repeat this process the desired number of times?

Comment: @MitchelPaulin what do you mean? Can you explain it with a sample? also I forgot to tell that each number of the original array must be used more or less the same times than the others if you count the occurrences in the resulting arrays

Comment: Your working sample contains 8, 3 in every output array, then your failed sample cannot contain 6, 1. Why?

Comment: @NullPointerException Ok now I see the problem. I was under the assumption that each shuffle had nothing to do with each other

Comment: @zlakad numbers can't be repeated on the resulting arrays, the third array already has 6,1

Comment: Perhaps continuously iterate the already shuffled source array to populate the target arrays, then shuffle each target array.

Comment: If I understood you, your goal is to distribute the numbers **uniformly as much as possible**?

Comment: @zlakad maybe yes, not sure of the meaning, but they must be used as far as posible the same number of times. I clarified the requirements on the start of the question editing it

Comment: +1 from me, but there are some ambiguities: what if you have original array like in your example (8 elements) and you want 3 arrays of size 2? I mean, in this case you cannot use _every_ number. Also, what would be the criteria for which numbers are 'privileged' - why 8 and 3 can be repeated and not 2 and 4?

Comment: @zlakad about your first question the user must enter the amount necessary to fit the requirement and about your second question i used random because none of them must be privileged, they must be used equally as far as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream`s to limit the shuffled list to `z` elements:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

List<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
  Collections.shuffle(numbers);
  List<Integer> list = numbers.stream().limit(z).collect(Collectors.toList());
  result.add(list);
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Maybe it could be done in a more elegant way, but the output should be something like this:

```
[[2, 8, 7, 3, 4, 6], [4, 3, 6, 5, 2, 8], [5, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: Creating a stream for this I think is overkill, just use ``numbers.sublist()``

Comment: @QBrute take in mind that numbers can't be repeated on the resulting arrays. Also each number of the original array must be used as far as possible the same number of times times than the others if you count the occurrences in the resulting arrays. Whould your algorithm work with these requirements?. Also, those functions works on Java 7?

Comment: More elegant way would be to re-write `shuffle` method just like in the original Java code (I think that is using Knuth algorithm), **but STOP** the shuffling after _six_ times (regarding the OP's example)

Comment: @zlakad Whould work with these requirements? "numbers can't be repeated on the resulting arrays" and " each number of the original array must be used as far as possible the same number of times times than the others if you count the occurrences in the resulting arrays"

Comment: using this algorithm I think that it's possible that not all the numbers whould be used the same number of times as far as possible and even probably some numbers whould not be used in the resulting arrays. I generated an array with all the numbers repeated the necessary number of times to make sure that i'm using all the numbers more or less the same number of times and that none of them leaves without being used

Comment: @NullPointerException This won't work with Java 7, as I'm using `Stream`s. Numbers won't be repeated, since I'm using the original list which doesn't contain repeated numbers. As for your other requirement, I'm not really sure what you mean by "use the same number as far as possible"?

Comment: @NullPointerException - It wouldn't work, but I commented the answer...

Answer (score 1):

#### The Idea

To make this work, we need

- `z < x` (length of each new lists < length of input list) or we couldn't fill the new lists without duplicates.
- `y·z` (number of lists · length of lists) has to be a multiple of `x` or some numbers would have to appear more often than others.

The idea is to

1. Shuffle the input list.
2. Repeat the input list such that we end up with `y·z` numbers. This can be done without actually repeating the list. The trick is to use the modulo `%` operator.
3. Evenly split the repeated input list into `y` lists of length `z`.
4. Shuffle each new list.

Input

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Shuffle

```
3 5 8 6 7 2 4 1
```

Repeat

```
3 5 8 6 7 2 4 1 3 5 8 6 7 2 4 1 3 5 8 6 7 2 4 1
```

Split

```
3 5 8 6 7 2    4 1 3 5 8 6    7 2 4 1 3 5    8 6 7 2 4 1
```

Shuffle each list

```
7 3 5 6 2 8    1 3 4 8 6 5    3 4 1 5 7 2    2 7 4 1 8 6
```

Shuffle the list of lists

```
1 3 4 8 6 5    2 7 4 1 8 6    7 3 5 6 2 8    3 4 1 5 7 2
```

#### The Program

This program should work in Java 7. However I did only test it with Java 11.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Shuffle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(splitShuffle(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 6, 3));
    }
    public static List<List<Integer>> splitShuffle(
            List<Integer> input, int newLength, int listCount) {        
        assert newLength * listCount % input.size() == 0 : "Cannot distribute numbers evenly";
        input = new ArrayList<>(input);
        Collections.shuffle(input);
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(listCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < listCount; ++i) {
            result.add(rotatingCopy(input, i * newLength, newLength));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(result);
        return result;
    }
    private static List<Integer> rotatingCopy(List<Integer> input, int startIndex, int length) {
        assert length < input.size() : "copy would have to contain duplicates";
        List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            copy.add(input.get((startIndex + i) % input.size()));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(copy);
        return copy;
    }
}
```

#### Example Outputs

I ran the program four times. Here are its outputs. Each line is one run of the program.

```
[[2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 3], [4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 8], [1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 8]]
[[2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 1], [4, 7, 2, 6, 8, 3], [1, 3, 5, 8, 6, 4]]
[[4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3], [5, 3, 8, 4, 6, 7], [5, 1, 2, 7, 3, 8]]
[[5, 3, 8, 2, 6, 4], [1, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3], [1, 6, 2, 8, 7, 4]]
```

As we can see, each number appears exactly two times and each sub-list has only unique numbers.

#### Completeness

At least for the input list `[1, 2, 3]` and `y=3, z=2` I could verify that all the possible 48 outputs can be generated. I know that there are 48 combinations by using the following bash command:

```
printf %s\\n {1..3}{1..3},{1..3}{1..3},{1..3}{1..3} | grep -Pv '(\d)\1' |
tr -d , | awk '{print $1, gsub(1,""), gsub(2,""), gsub(3,"")}' |
grep -F ' 2 2 2' | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Where is number **1** in the third output?

Comment: Found the bug. Should have been `% input.size()` instead of `% size`.

Comment: Nice try, BUT... Once you shuffle the original, and give me 
 the output and the other variables, resulting arrays are predictable. I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: Really? I don't think you can predict the output, but lets try. Here's a simple case for you: `x=3, y=3, z=2`. The input is `[1, 2, 3]` and the shuffled version is `[2, 3, 1]`. What is the output? One hint: there are multiple answers, so you shouldn't be able to give me the output I received. However, if you could give me one valid result that can never be generated by this program, then I would agree with you and look for another solution.

Comment: I read your steps not your code, so after repeat I've got **231231**, and after splitting **23**, **12**, **31**. Am I right? Ops - I didn't read _Shuffle each list and the list of lists._

Comment: The repeat step is correct, but the final result is not. Remember that after splitting, each list is shuffled and the list of lists is also shuffled. This step has no example "image".

Comment: Sorry, pal. My bad, so... +1 from me.

Comment: @Socowi thanks for your answer but i forgot a very importar requirment: The resulting lists must not contain the same numbers! (ordering them they must be different). Can your algorithm work with that requirement?

Comment: @Socowi also a very important point is that about this "number of lists · length of lists) has to be a multiple of x" I'm not sure if I understand you but the user must be able to enter a non multiple of X length for that variables and the algorithm must fill the remaining slots of the lists with more random numbers. Because of that i told that "Each number of the original array must be used as far as possible the same number of times than the others"

Comment: @NullPointerException I think this is the right answer. Maybe it can be done efficiently (matter of speed). Why you can't write the test (repeating 1000000 or so times), for example counting the repetition of each element and see if the elements fulfill the uniform randomness?

Comment: @NullPointerException Yes and Yes. The lists will be different from each other as long as `z<x`. If you remove the first `assert` line it also works for non-multiple of `X`. The numbers will be as evenly distributed as possible.

Comment: thank you @Socowi but this algorithm doesn't fit exactly my needs. I will explain you the best I can (english is not my native language). This algorithm will generate combinations for something similar to a lottery, so all the combinations will be sorted after generated and all the combinations must be different. Also all the combinations must be randomized. After adding Collection.sort instead of suffle in rotatingCopy method, I get these outputs for this imput splitShuffle(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 6, 3) --> [[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]]

Comment: As you can see when I sort them (i will display it sorted because it's something similar to a Lottery) I'm getting combinations with more or less consecutive numbers, and I must avoid this. It's a requirement, I need randomized numbers. Also there is something that I don't understand completly in your algorithm (sorry but i'm very bad at maths). It seems that it's like a rotating wheel of numbers.. so if it's a wheel, something tells me that it's possible to get repeated combinations that are already present, because if it's a wheel it will return to the same values. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right and wrong at the same time :). Yes, the sorted lists are very consecutive, but that's only because we have to pick six out of eight numbers. That way all but two numbers *have* to be direct successors. The idea of a repeating wheel is correct. However, before rotating the wheel, we shuffle the numbers written on it -- so it's ok.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer @Socowi Then, it is not impossible to get repeated combinations? 100% safe? Also, how can be solved the problem of the common consecutive numbers? I tryed with combinations of length of  four for example and I'm getting also very consecutive numbers

Comment: Of course the combinations will repeat when you generate a lot of them. There is only a finite amount of combinations. Generating infinitely many different combinations is impossible. At some point they have to repeat -- not only for this program, but for all programs.

Comment: @Socowi How can be calculated the maximum number of allowed combinations? Also how can be solved the problems of the consecutive numbers? Maybe the idea of a rotating wheel is not the best option for a lottery objective (because too much consecutive numbers are not welcome and it's mandatory to have very randomized numbers)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183203/discussion-between-socowi-and-nullpointerexception).

Comment: All possible combinations in set of **n elements, with **k** size is **n!/k!(n-k)!**... (x! means x factorial)

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to shuffle the original List, then continuously iterate until the target Lists are populated, then shuffle each target List.  This will keep the occurrence of each number balanced.  It also works if `numbersPerCombination` > `numbers.size()`.

```
public class FairLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        List<List<Integer>> fairLists = getOptimizedCombinations(numbers, 6, 3);
        System.out.println(fairLists);
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> getOptimizedCombinations(List<Integer> numbers, int numbersPerCombination, int desiredCombinations){
        List<Integer> source = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
        Collections.shuffle(source);

        List<List<Integer>> fairNumbersLists = new ArrayList<>(desiredCombinations);

        int sourceIndex = 0;
        while (desiredCombinations > 0) {

            List<Integer> fairNumbers = new ArrayList<>(numbersPerCombination);
            for (int i = 0; i < numbersPerCombination; i++) {
                fairNumbers.add(source.get(sourceIndex));
                sourceIndex++;
                if (sourceIndex == source.size()) {
                    sourceIndex = 0;
                }
            }

            Collections.shuffle(fairNumbers);
            fairNumbersLists.add(fairNumbers);

            desiredCombinations--;
        }

        Collections.shuffle(fairNumbersLists);
        return fairNumbersLists;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way you can write a program that works for `numbersPerCombination > numbers.size()`. For the list `[1, 2]` and `y=z=3` your program gave me `[[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]` which violates *»only unique numbers in each list«* and *»sorted lists must be different from each other«*.

Comment: sorry @AndrewS I forgot some rules, but now all of them are written, please can you adapt your algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

During our chat you asked me to write the code regarding combinations, **SO THIS ISN'T AN ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION, JUST THE CODE YOU CAN EXPLORE**:

```
public class Combination {

    private Combination() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param n:
     *            n-set
     * @param m:
     *            m-subset
     * @return number of combinations C(n, m) = (n(n - 1)...(n - m + 1)) / m!
     */
    public static BigInteger C(int n, int m) {
        if (m > n) {
            return BigInteger.ZERO;
        } else {
            if ((n - m) > m) {
                return C(n, (n - m));
            }
        }
        BigInteger numerator = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.ONE;

        for (int i = n; i > m; i--) {
            numerator = numerator.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }

        for (int i = (n - m); i > 1; i--) {
            denominator = denominator.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }

        return numerator.divide(denominator);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param <T>
     *            Type
     * @param elements
     *            List of elements to combine
     * @param numberOfRequiredElements
     *            must be less or equal to elements.size()
     * @param combinatios
     *            result: List&lt;List&lt;T&gt;&gt; of all combinations
     * @param temp
     *            used for recursive purposes
     * @return combinations<br>
     * 
     *         Example of usage:<br>
     *         List&lt;Integer&gt; elements = new ArrayList&lt;&gt;();<br>
     *         for (int i = 1; i &lt;= 7; i++) {<br>
     *         &emsp;elements.add(i);<br>
     *         }<br>
     *         List&lt;Integer&gt; temp = new ArrayList&lt;&gt;();<br>
     *         List&lt;List&lt;Integer&gt;&gt; combinations = new
     *         ArrayList&lt;&gt;();<br>
     *         System.out.println(Combination.allCombinations(elements, 6,
     *         combinations, temp));<br>
     *
     */
    public static <T> List<List<T>> allCombinations(List<T> elements, int numberOfRequiredElements,
            List<List<T>> combinatios, List<T> temp) {
        if (numberOfRequiredElements == 0) {
            // System.out.print(temp);
            combinatios.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                temp.add(elements.get(i));
                List<T> subList = elements.subList(i + 1, elements.size());
                allCombinations(subList, numberOfRequiredElements - 1, combinatios, temp);
                temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        return combinatios;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     *            Not required for this purpose
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int NO_OF_ELEMENS = 10;
        int REQURED_COMBINATION_SIZE = 6;

        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= NO_OF_ELEMENS; i++) {
            elements.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("This is an example of using methods in this class\n");
        System.out.println("Elements are " + elements + " (size = " + elements.size() + ")");
        System.out.println("Requred size of combination is " + REQURED_COMBINATION_SIZE);
        System.out.println("Number of all combinations is " + Combination.C(NO_OF_ELEMENS, REQURED_COMBINATION_SIZE));
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("All combinations are:");
        Combination.allCombinations(elements, REQURED_COMBINATION_SIZE, combinations, temp);
        int i = 0;
        for (List<Integer> combination : combinations) {
            System.out.println(++i + "\t" + combination);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this code can be helpful.
P.S. Sorry about unreadable comments - I wrote this earlier in NetBeans and now I'm using IntelliJ...

**EDIT**: Using long instead of `BigInteger` for calculate number of combinations... (Personally, I don't recommend this).

```
public static long noOfCombinations(int n, int m){

    //this part is for fewer multiplications
    //b/c 4 out of 6 has the same number of combinations as 2 out of 6
    if (m > n) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if ((n - m) > m) {
            return noOfCombinations(n, (n - m));
        }
    }

    long numerator = 1;
    long denominator = 1;

    //these two loops are for partial factorial
    for (int i = n; i > m; i--) {
        numerator *= i;
    }

    for (int i = (n - m); i > 1; i--) {
        denominator *= i;
    }

    // no of combinations
    return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will study your code and check if I can imagine an approach with it. BTW, if you can remember from our chat yesterday, when i work with sets of 40 numbers and combinations of for example eight or ten numbers, then we are talking millions of combinations and the CPU blocks calculating.

Comment: For example, with 40 numbers and 8 size for the combination, there are 76904685 combinations and the CPU get's blocked calculating. Can you imagine a variation of this algorithm for getting only the desired combinations (for example 50) from that 76904685 combinations randomly? For example dividing 76904685 between 50 for getting an interval and getting the 50 combinations with that interval or something similar. The objective is to not calculate all the combinations but only the desired combinations and getting not just the first combinations (because if so the numbers will not be random)

Comment: Yes, there is always a problem with hardware resources. For example, `BigInteger` is theoretically infinite, yet limited by actual memory... I know what are you asking, I will try to solve your problem. Unfortunately, right now I'm very busy...

Comment: thank you @zlakad I hope you will be able to solve this, It's very frustrating

Comment: @NullPointerException actually it IS frustrating! My idea was to write the method with one additional parameter `numberOfDesiredCombinations`. First I'd shuffle the elements and use the recursion only `numberOfDesiredCombinations` times. But, my head isn't working right now, and I cannot figure how to achieve that. With your experience, maybe you can do it. I'm sorry I wasn't so much helpful...

Comment: Also, every code that use the recursion can be written without the recursion, so...

Comment: ok @zlakad thank you for your help, if you imagine a solution for that please tell me, btw thanks a lot

Comment: can you migrate your method to use longs instead of BigInteger please?

Comment: @NullPointerException, here you are. BTW, I was thinking about some modifications of my algorithm to extract some combinations and I'm almost sure that it cannot be done. You see, this recursion goes backward... Sorry, and good luck, friend. (Feel free to ask me anything else).

Comment: Little explanation: number of cmb in set of 40 elements size 8 is the same as number of cmb in set of 40 elements size 32. The formula is 40! / 32! * 8!. This is: 40 *39*38*37*36*35*34*33*(32!) / (32!) * 8!. I cut 32! from the numerator _and_ denominator, so it becomes 40*39*38*37*36*35*34*33 / 8*7*6*4*3*2... That's why I swap `m` with `n - m` for reducing multiplications... Everything I did isn't necessary, but it is much more efficient than: (40*39*38*...*1) / (32*31*30*...*1) * (8*7*...*1)

Comment: Risking to be boring, I'll explain how the main algorithm works: E.g. set of 40 elements, 8 desired numbers: **[1, give me all combinations from set [2 to 40] size 7]**. Next step of recursion: **[1, 2, give me all combinations from set [3 to 40] size 6]**, etc.

Comment: thank you so much @zlakad thank you a lot for all your help!